# How to alphabetize all members in Eclipse Outline view?

Tags: java, eclipse, alphabetical, outline

In the Eclipse Outline view, there is a button to sort members alphabetically. However, it seems to sort members by category first, and then by alphabet, such that the resulting list is not in fact alphabetical. I don't see it, but is is there a way to ignore categories and sort everything in the list together alphabetically?

Example class:

```java
package com.foo;

public class Foo {
    private static int zurklfutz;
    public int hoopliket;

    protected void terfwad() {
    }

    public void badelfrok() {
    }

    public Foo() {
    }

    private void adelbrecht() {
    }

    public static void zebulon() {
    }

    static int nerdiftun;
}
```

Results categorized, and then alphabetized within categories resulting in not-very-alphabetic list:

[image]

Comment: The Quick Outline view (Ctrl+O) sorts alphabetically if you have activated the appropriate option in the menu at the top right of the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementComparator` this is not possible.

The sort always sorts first by categories using the order defined in "Preferences > Java > Appearance > Members Sort Order".

The pop-up "Quick Outline" (Navigate > Quick Outline, Ctrl+O, ⌘+O on macs) does have an alphabetic sort option in the menu at the top right.

Comment: In the Quick Outline view (Ctrl+O) it is different.

Comment: How infuriating. But thank you!